# Fade/transition tailwind class to something else over certain amount of time?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

Is there a way to set `bg-red-300` and fade/transition it to `bg-transparent` or different bg class over 2 seconds or do I need javascript for this? I want an element to highlight and then return to normal after 2 secs. Thank you!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You may create your own animation with config file

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      
      // that is animation class
      animation: {
        fade: 'fadeOut 5s ease-in-out',
      },

      // that is actual animation
      keyframes: theme => ({
        fadeOut: {
          '0%': { backgroundColor: theme('colors.red.300') },
          '100%': { backgroundColor: theme('colors.transparent') },
        },
      }),
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Use it like

```
<div class="w-40 h-40 animate-fade"></div>
```

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wfzSFIYmBF)

P.S. However you may probably need some Javascript to trigger `animate-fade` classlist toggling or something as animation will proceed no matter does block is in viewport or not.

Comment: Cool, very interesting solution. Thanks! Where can I learn more about what's available to put in the `colors.red.300` part? I tried `colors.red.300/50` and `colors.red.300.50` for opacity but it didn't seem to work. Thank you!

Comment: It is basically javascript syntax of getting values by key in any `theme` object of config (Tailwind default included) - `colors` has key `red`, `red` has key `300`. `fadeOut` animation in my example can be extracted with `theme('keyframes.fadeOut')` or `theme(keyframes[fadeOut])`. About second part - nice question short syntax was introduced at 2.2 and I believe has place only on front part as it is not registered in config. The only option I see is to pass standard CSS `rgba()` where `red.300` should be present in RGB value but it's not cool...

Comment: Ah thanks! So instead of `theme('colors.red.300')` I would do something like `rgba(x, x, x, 0.5)` ? I just tried and got `Tailwind CSS: rgba is not defined`

Comment: Blockquote it like `{ backgroundColor: "rgba(x,y,z,a)" }`. It thinks it is JS function which is not. You need to pass it as a string

Comment: Posted your answer (with attribution) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71449617/1459653 Thanks!

Comment: What if i need to do fade in and fade out at the same element

Answer (score 17):

You could utilize tailwind transition property

> transition-opacity

```
<div class="h-8 w-8 bg-blue-600 transition-opacity ease-in duration-700 opacity-100 hover:opacity-0"></div>
```

refer https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/K39G8oMKkw)